# Login using SQL and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

The problem here is that I am getting an error 207 from SQL and its acting like the columns arent lined up.  I debugged but to no avail.  I have 4 columns in the database(BankAccount)
accountID, balance, userID, password with values(identity, 5000, test, test)

Now that being said my code for the login is below

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True");
            try
            {

                dbConnection.Open();
                dbConnection.ChangeDatabase("BankAccount");
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT userID, password FROM Checking WHERE userID ="  + user.Text + " AND password = '" + password.Text + "'", dbConnection);


                SqlDataReader curUser = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (curUser.Read())
                {
                    Session["userID"] = curUser["userID"].ToString();
                    Session["password"] = curUser["password"].ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                    badLogin.Text = "<p style='color:red'><strong>Incorrect ID or password.<strong></p>";
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                Response.Write("<p>Error code " + exception.Number
                    + ": " + exception.Message + "</p>");
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: How is it not working? What do you mean by "columns aren't lined up"? (Also, why aren't you hashing passwords or using SQL command parameters?)

Comment: ***Please use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection.***

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  Have you tried stepping through the code to make sure you are passing what you think you are?  Have you tried executing the query directly in Management Studio to make sure it returns what you think it should?  In other words, what have you done to debug this and what were your results?

Comment: well i executed through sql management studio and everything checks out i have what are supposed to be in the desired rows.  When i click submit on the form it gives me this error 
Problem is when i click submit it gives me an error that
 Error code 207: Invalid column name 'test'. when i named the column names right in the database//that being said the information in the column userID==test not //////'test' is not the column name its the info inside the userID column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var cmdText = "SELECT userID, password FROM Checking " +
                  "WHERE userID =@userID AND password = @password";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", user.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
    connection.Open();

    var curUser = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (curUser.Read())
    {
        Session["userID"] = curUser["userID"].ToString();
        Session["password"] = curUser["password"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess only problem being I havent got this far yet so the cmd.parameters doesnt make sense to me quite yet

Comment: [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) prevents SQL injection.

Comment: That still leads me to my question though where was I going wrong

Comment: Your forget single quote for User Id - `'"  + user.Text + "'`, although you have them for password.

Answer (score 0):

The error 207 points to a mismatch on one of the column names.

Comment: you can see for yourself by googling... https://www.google.co.uk/#q=error+207+from+SQL+

Comment: yeah I saw that but I cant figure out how to fix it.  My column names are fine I don't see where I am going wrong

Comment: Did you try doing a global search for the word 'test'? It maybe possible you find it elsewhere in your application, yet its affecting your program. Also watch out for spaces, that too can cause mismatches in column names!

Comment: Additionally, the solution below by WIN is the preferred method for SQL queries, it helps prevent sql injection attacks.